# Run parallel jobs in oracle

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing

I have a table `jobs` which is as follows:

```
JOB_ID STATUS

 1      N     
 2      N     
 3      N     
 4      N     
 5      N     
 6      N     
 7      N     
 8      N     
 9      N     
10      N     
11      N     
12      N
```

What I have to do is select 4 job ids at once,set their status to 'Y' and as soon as 1 job is completed another should start running. At any instance, there must be 4 jobs running.

I did research on how to achieve and most of the documents suggested using scheduler jobs. However, I could not figure out how to do it.

Here is a code sample of what I have done:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_processTask
(
  JobID NUMBER
)
AS
 vblSQL VARCHAR2(32767);
 vJobID NUMBER;

BEGIN
  vJobID:=JobID;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'insert into job_logs values('''||vJobID||''',sysdate,sysdate)';
  vblSQL:='UPDATE jobs
           SET status=''Y''
           WHERE job_ID='||vJobID;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(vblSQL);
  Dbms_Output.put_line(vblSQL);
END;
/
```

And then passing 4 different job ids at once as follows:

```
BEGIN
  sp_processTask(1);
  sp_processTask(2);
  sp_processTask(3);
  sp_processTask(4);
END;
```

What should I do to pass another job id as soon as one flag is set to 'Y'? I am using oracle.

Comment: Do these jobs have to be run in sequence?  Seems like your time would be better spent in learning how to use DBMS_SCHEDULER rather than writing your own.

Comment: They have to be in the order 1,2,3,4,... I know I have to use DBMS_SCHEDULER, but I can't understand how.

Comment: http://database-geek.com/2011/03/20/oracle-dbms_scheduler-part-3-job-chains/

Comment: @OldProgrammer : First of all that's not parallel processing,it's serial. And what do you suggest if I have to run thousands of PL/SQL blocks?Write a script for each and every block?